# SQL Server : use LIKE inside a CASE statement to replace characters in string

Tags: sql-server, replace, case

Apologies for poorly worded question.

I have the following column `description` with contents like:

```
2511420s5
38114CR
2510014IND
```

I want to get rid of the `s5`,`CR`and `IND`using a `CASE` statement.

Something like:

```
select 
    CASE 
       WHEN description LIKE ('%CRT%', '%IND%', '%MR%') THEN ''
       ELSE description
    END as test 
from table
```

So to summarize, I want to strip the `S5` from my string if it exists.

I have a list of about 15 possibilities so don't want to use a nested replace statement.

Can this be done with `CASE` or is there a better option?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is no better rule; i.e. the text is not always at the end of the string, you could store the ignore tokens in a table, join and examine;

```
;with ignore(token) as ( --a real table is better
    select 's5'  union
    select 'ind' union
    select 'cr'
)
select distinct
    id, -- need > 1 col
    case when ignore.token is null then description else '' end
from table
    left join ignore on description like '%' + token + '%'
```

Comment: On SQL Server 2008 R2, `SELECT * from Table_1;` gives me:

    id    description
    {{1,     2511420s5},
    {2,     38114CR},
    {3,     2510014IND}}

but executing query give me:

    id    description
    {{1,     <empty or null>},
    {2,     <empty or null>},
    {3     <empty or null>}}

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct query:

```
;with ignore(token) as (
    select 's5'  union
    select 'ind' union
    select 'cr'
)
select distinct
    id, -- need > 1 col
    case when ignore.token is null then description 
    else REPLACE(description, ignore.token,  '')
    end
from table_1
    left join ignore on description like '%' + token + '%';
```

Comment: Thanks man, 100%. 

Alex K just pipped you to the post. Thanks again, appreciated.